# Getting media:thumbnail url from rss feed

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, rss

I have this RSS feed(sample supplied below) and I want to extract the url from the media:thumbnail object, but I haven't been successful in doing so(my code supplied below). All the examples I found here had a different format to their xml. How can I get the url from the xml. Thanks in advance.

The xml:

```
<item>
    <title>
        <![CDATA[
        أردوغان: هناك محاولة لحماية شخص ما في حادث مقتل خاشقجي
        ]]>
    </title>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[
        الرئيس التركي، رجب طيب إردوغان، يقول إن هناك محاولة لحماية        شخص أو بعض الأشخاص في حادث مقتل الصحفي السعودي، جمال خاشقجي، وإنه يجب أن يُنهى   موضوع مكان الجثة بشكل سريع.
        ]]>
    </description>
    <link>http://www.bbc.co.uk/arabic/middleeast-46017209</link>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.bbc.co.uk/arabic/middleeast-46017209</guid>
    <pubDate>Tue, 30 Oct 2018 11:15:25 GMT</pubDate>
    <media:thumbnail width="976" height="549" url="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/1795/production/_104073060_mediaitem104073056.jpg"/>
 </item>
```

my code:

```
articles = response.xpath('//channel/item')
for article in articles:
    item = ArtscraperItem()
    thumb="thumbnail"
    item['pic']=article.xpath('/*[local-name() = "%s"]/@url' %thumb )
```

Comment: Try `'./*[local-name() = "%s"]/@url'`. Note that `/*` means *match any root node* while `./*` means *match child of current node (`article`)*